# Strange CSS border issue on Opera

Tags: html, css

I have a link with some text inside it which works nice on all browsers but on opera, rounded corners from the bottom does not work.

I use this css class for the link:

```
.currentJob:link, .currentJob:visited {
    border: 1px solid #dcd3ce;
    background: #ffffff url(../images/applyIcon.jpg) right top no-repeat;
    margin: .5em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
 }
```

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EG6sS/1/).

Does anyone know how I can fix that in opera? What is strange is that link:hover works in Opera perfectly.

Comment: should be -webkit-border-radius

Comment: @DerekSchlesselman This seems to not be the issue, because Opera takes this into account: `border-radius: 10px;` but indeed I fixed this too.

Comment: add the -o-border-radius

Comment: If you remove the background colour of .jobCloseDate, do the rounded corners appear on the bottom?

Comment: @Tyanna Yes.... but I need that color...

Comment: That was just a 'debugging' question. :) Try adding  position:relative; to .jobCloseDate?

Comment: @Tyanna The fiddle is there, open it in Opera and try it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a great solution, adding a border radius on `.jobCloseDate` works:

http://jsfiddle.net/EG6sS/3/

```
.jobCloseDate {
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
```

Alternate solution.  It's kludgy, but it works.  Removed overflow and shifted down the last element so that the "white pixels" are not visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/EG6sS/21/

```
.currentJob:link, .currentJob:visited {
    border: 1px solid #dcd3ce;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background: #ffffff url(../images/applyIcon.jpg) right top no-repeat;
    margin: .5em 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    /* removed overflow */
}
.jobTitle {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #006A8A;
    margin: .6em 45px .1em .6em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}
.jobLocation {
    /* removed .5em from the bottom margin and added it to the top position on the next element */
    margin: 0 .7em 1em .7em;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
.jobCloseDate {
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: .5em;
    display: block;
    background-color: #006A8A;
    /* added the following styles */
    border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: .5em;
    left: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-right: -2px;
    border: inherit;
    border-top: 0;
}
.currentJob:hover, .currentJob:visited:hover {
    border: 1px solid #006A8A;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Yes I noticed this but on hover it appears small pixels of white on the bottom corners..

Comment: There's now a solution that gets rid of the ugly white pixels.

Answer (score 2):

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
webkit-border-radius: 10px;
khtml-border-radius: 10px;
```

Only `border-radius: 10px;` is enough. The `border-radius` property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome, Safari 5+, and Opera.

But the disturbing part in your code is

```
.jobCloseDate {
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
font-style: italic;
padding: .5em;
display: block;
background-color: #006A8A;
}
```

Change the above code as

```
.jobCloseDate {
text-align: center;
color: #ffffff;
font-style: italic;
padding: .5em;
display: block;
border-radius:0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
background-color: #006A8A;
}
```

I have added `border-radius:0 0 0.5em 0.5em;` for the block because, in opera without this one, that `jobCloseDate` is not giving the rounded corners.

Please see this link for the full code http://jsfiddle.net/EG6sS/9/

[image]

Comment: Its a good idea to *look* at the existing answers before you post to make sure you're not duplicating what's already been posted.

Comment: I was not duplicating, while I was making modifications that previous answer was posted.

Answer (score -1):

An idea,

try `-webkit-border-radius` and move it up so that:

1. `-webkit-border-radius: 10px;`
2. `border-radius: 10px;`

Comment: Opera applies the border-radius just fine, the problem is that `overflow: hidden` is ignored.